# htaccess rewrite url to remove the /folder/ but leave everything else after

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use htaccess to remove the sub directory from the url and leave everything else.

The current links look like this...

http://blog.domain.com/blog/page-title

I need the links to look like this...

http://blog.domain.com/page-title

there is an installation of WP at both locations with the same DB (different physical databases)

so I have tried this...

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ blog/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1
```

and lots of other things, just cant seem to work it out with all the attempts.

Would love a little help on this

Comment: Do you already have rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: Can you please mark by answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]
```

This will make every links like:

```
http://blog.domain.com/page-title
```

behave as if they were:

```
http://blog.domain.com/blog/page-title
```

---

And if you want the inverse effect, meaning that all link with `/blog/stuff` change into `/stuff` try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I had to put it at the very first position but it works... AWESOME! Thanks again!